# How to select a item from a context menu and displayed it a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox and a browse button next to it. The combobox display all local SQL instances and the browse button displays a context menu with all remote SQL instances. I got all these done. Now I need to select an item from the context menu and then display it in the combobox as a selecteditem.

I think there are at least two events involved here: MouseDown event in context menu for the selection and selection changed event from the combobox. And these two events are one next to each other. How can I achieve it. How do I have one event to trigger another? I tried some code but it doesn't work:

```
                    <ComboBox Name ="comboSql"
                              Height="22"
                              Margin="10,0,20,0"
                              Width="250"
                              IsEditable="True"
                              Text="{Binding SelectedSqlServer, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding LocalSqlServers}">

                    </ComboBox>
                    <Button x:Name="BrowseButton"
                            FontWeight="Bold"
                            Width="80"
                            Height="22"
                            Content="Browse"
                            Click="BrowseButton_Click">

                        <Button.ContextMenu>                               
                            <ContextMenu Name="BrowseButtonContext"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding RemoteSqlServers}"
                                         MouseDown="Select_Click">                               
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Button.ContextMenu>
                    </Button>

   public string SelectedSqlServer
    {
        get { return selectedSqlServer.ToString(); }

    }

   public void Select_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedSqlServer = (System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu)sender;
        comboSql.Text = selectedSqlServer.ToString();           
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code for how to accomplish this:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cb1" Width="100" Height="40">

    </ComboBox>

        <Button x:Name="button1" Width="100" Height="40" Content="Browse">
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Name="context1">

                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetUpContextMenu();
        SetUpComboBox();

    }

    private void SetUpComboBox()
    {
        cb1.Items.Add("Sql1");
        cb1.Items.Add("Sql2");
        cb1.Items.Add("Sql3");
    }


    private void SetUpContextMenu()
    {
        MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem();
        item1.Header = "Remote1";
        item1.Click += AddToComboBox;
        item1.CommandParameter = "Remote1";

        MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem();
        item2.Header = "Remote2";
        item2.Click += AddToComboBox;
        item2.CommandParameter = "Remote2";

        MenuItem item3 = new MenuItem();
        item3.Header = "Remote3";
        item3.Click += AddToComboBox;
        item3.CommandParameter = "Remote3";

        context1.Items.Add(item1);
        context1.Items.Add(item2);
        context1.Items.Add(item3);

    }

    public void AddToComboBox(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem item = (MenuItem)sender;
        int index = cb1.Items.Add(item.CommandParameter);
        cb1.SelectedIndex = index;
    }
}
```

I'm adding the "Text" of the contextmenustrip item to the combobox. Make sure you have a way to reference your actual SQL instance/connection string/whatever you're using.

Comment: Is ItemClicked n built in event for ContextMenu? i can't find it there and got an error.  This is for WPF.

Comment: Updated my answer with a working WPF solution for this.

You're right, there isn't an item clicked in WPF for contextmenus. You need to create a "click" event for each of the menuitems.  I've used the CommandParameter as the ConnectionString/DataSource/Whatever to pass through.  Enjoy!

Comment: What kind of event should trigger the selection of the context menu? There is no Click event for it. I tried MouseDown event and it doesn't trigger.

Comment: The context menu is automatically triggered on a right-click of the button